# Button background color in sencha

Tags: css, sencha-touch

I am new to sencha touch.
How do we change the background color of a button to white? I have a button with two images in each corner. I want the button to be plain white.
I tried using css like this:

```
.quest {
background: url(../images/quest.jpg) no-repeat left,
       url(../images/rightarrow.jpg) no-repeat right;
       background-color: white;
       border: none;
       border-color:white;
       padding-left: 50px;
       text-align: left;
}
```

My button is here:

```
{
    xtype: 'button',
    text: '<div class="quest">Info</div>',
    labelWidth: '100%',
    name: '',
    handler: function() {                 
    }
}
```

My button has grey borders (Grey default button color in sencha) with white color in mid. How do i make it completely white? Please help.

I have even tried:

```
style: "background-color: white"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using 'cls' attribute solved my problem.

```
               {

                   xtype: 'button',
                   cls: 'btn',
                   text: '<div class="person">People</div>',
                   labelWidth: '100%',


                },
```

In my app.css define

```
.btn
{
background-color: white !important;
background-image: none;
}
```

We have to redefine both background-color and background-image properties so that the default sencha-touch.css properties are overridden. Thank you Thiem Nguyen for your help.

Comment: Nicely done !! The only thing is then we lose the pressed-cls feel. Any idea how to add that in too ?

Answer (score 6):

This should render your desired button :)

```
config: {
        ui: 'plain',
        text: 'Your Text',
        style: 'background-color:white;'
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. But I have already mentioned that I have used tha too. Its not working.

Comment: have you tried `ui: 'plain'` yet? I've just tried to create a button with those configs and it works well

Comment: {  xtype: 'button',
                        config: {
                            ui: 'plain',
                            text: 'Your Text',
                            style: 'background-color:white;'
                        } } I have tried like this.

Comment: did you say that you want the button to be plain white? so what does it look like?

Comment: it looks the same default grey button. Anything inside config :{} is not getting recognised. Even the text doesnot appear if put inside config{}

Comment: please let me see your entire definition for that button

Comment: {

                        xtype: 'button',
                        config: {
                            ui: 'plain',
                            text: 'My Text',
                            style: 'background-color:white;'
                        },

                       
                    
                       
                       
                    //    style: "background-color: white",
                        handler: function() {
                          
                        }
                    },

Comment: it seems that you want to create that button directly instead of define your own class. Try taking them out of `config` and delete `config` I mean `{ xtype: 'button', ui: 'plain', text: 'My Text', style: 'background-color:white;' }`

Comment: Tried that too. It still appears grey in color:( I can make it white using css But near the border it still appears grey

Comment: That's quite weird. Let's check it out online. Please go to sencha touch 2 documentation, and find Ext.Panel. These's a live code editor there, the only thing I've changed is: `var button = Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
      text: 'Button',
      ui: 'plain',
    style: 'background-color: white; color: red;'  
 });`. What did you get?

Comment: i will see that. I need your help in the below query too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10026082/placeholder-in-sencha

Comment: style is deprecated as a property directly on the Component. Please put it inside the config object, and retrieve it using "this.config.style". I get this error in console

Answer (score 4):

Just like Thiem Nguyen said, this will work

```
           {
                xtype:'button',
                text:'text',
                ui:'plain',
                style:'background-color:white'
            }
```